# Shortest C code to reverse a string

Tags: c, string, reverse

Not counting the function signature (just the body) can anybody produce C code shorter than this function that will reverse a string and return the result as a pointer to the reversed string.. (not using a string reverse library function either)?

```
char * reverse_str(char * s)
{
   char c,*f=s,*p=s;while(*p)p++;while(--p>s){c=*p;*p=*s;*s++=c;}return f;
}
```

Comment: this function doesn't even work, you're erasing the string you're trying to reverse. abcd will become dccd. You need a second parameter to hold the new string. If you just want it to be short but not work as intended, {return s;} is the answer.

Comment: Yes. Why do you want to know?

Comment: And writing it on one line won't make it shorter ...

Comment: [`return strrev(s);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrev)

Comment: "can anybody produce C code shorter than this" - Yes, I can do this.

Comment: @KennyTM: Unlucky, goalposts have been moved.

Comment: Has the Obfuscated C contest started again?

Answer (score 2):

not much longer, but it works.

```
#include <string.h>

/* precondition: s!=const && s!=NULL && *s!='\0' */
char *mystrrev(char *s)
{
  char *a=s,*e=s+strlen(s)-1;
  while( a<e )
  {
    char c=*a;
    *a++=*e;
    *e--=c;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: where, when preconditions are ok?

Comment: @Kedar: segmentation fault probably occured because you passed it a string literal or constant, which you shouldn't have done since it takes a `char *` and not a `const char *`.  You may have even gotten a compiler warning telling you not to do that.